# how to save sortable items in mvc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, items

i have been working on my carousel items. i need to have a sortable list views in order for me to choose the appropriate format of details in the actual site.

i was able to do the sortable items using this command in jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#subsortsortable tbody.content").sortable();
    $("#subsortsortable tbody.content").disableSelection();

    $("tbody.subcontent").sortable();
    $("tbody.subcontent").disableSelection();
});
```

then i added another jquery ui 1.7.1 in the site master:
http://www.wil-linssen.com/musings/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

i need to save the sorted items i dragged so when i click the refresh button. the new sorted items will be displayed

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do and works fine for me, i have a hidden field that i throw the values as comma separated string. Example:

```
$('#refresh').click(function() {
     var items = $('#sortable').sortable('toArray');

     $('#sortablevalues').val(items);
});
```